Add SVG marker to SVG Map using JS
I would like to add a SVG marker to a SVG Map that is in an iframe tag. The add is done via the press of a button on the HTML page.
<input type="button" onclick="addMarker()">
<script type = "text/javascript" src="./resources/javascript/marker.js"></script>

The addMarker() function is in the marker.js file.
The SVG marker that I would like to add is a standalone svg file in my Visual Studio Code project:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" id="marker" height="44" version="1.1" width="44" viewBox="0 0 25 25">
  <g transform="translate(0 -1028.4)">
    <path d="m12.031 1030.4c-3.8657 0-6.9998 3.1-6.9998 7 0 1.3 0.4017 2.6 1.0938 3.7 0.0334 0.1 0.059 0.1 0.0938 0.2l4.3432 8c0.204 0.6 0.782 1.1 1.438 1.1s1.202-0.5 1.406-1.1l4.844-8.7c0.499-1 0.781-2.1 0.781-3.2 0-3.9-3.134-7-7-7zm-0.031 3.9c1.933 0 3.5 1.6 3.5 3.5 0 2-1.567 3.5-3.5 3.5s-3.5-1.5-3.5-3.5c0-1.9 1.567-3.5 3.5-3.5z" fill="#c0392b"/>
    <path d="m12.031 1.0312c-3.8657 0-6.9998 3.134-6.9998 7 0 1.383 0.4017 2.6648 1.0938 3.7498 0.0334 0.053 0.059 0.105 0.0938 0.157l4.3432 8.062c0.204 0.586 0.782 1.031 1.438 1.031s1.202-0.445 1.406-1.031l4.844-8.75c0.499-0.963 0.781-2.06 0.781-3.2188 0-3.866-3.134-7-7-7zm-0.031 3.9688c1.933 0 3.5 1.567 3.5 3.5s-1.567 3.5-3.5 3.5-3.5-1.567-3.5-3.5 1.567-3.5 3.5-3.5z" fill="#e74c3c" transform="translate(0 1028.4)"/>
  </g>
</svg>

The addMarker() function looks like this:
// ADD MARKER TO MAP
function addMarker() {
    let marker = document.querySelector(".marker");
    const add = document.getElementById("map").contentDocument.documentElement;
    add.appendChild(marker);
};

For some reason the marker is not appearing when I press the button; I think it has to do with the how I am defining the marker (retrieving the marker SVG)?

The document for addMarker will not be the document you want/need.

you'll have to get that code to execute in the iframe, because iframes are separate documents. Your page can see the iframe tag but it cannot see the iframe content. If it's your own content, you can use a postMessage channel to let the iframed page know it needs to do something, but if it's not: too bad. It's not your page, you don't get to mess with it =)

Regarding the source of the document in the iframe -- is it on the same domain?
